# How to turn compiz on?

Tags: compiz

I've installed Compiz with the Applications->Ubuntu Software Center, but it does not change the way <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> animates.

Also, if I type "compiz" in the "run application" it hides all, and as I walk with the mouse everything gets back to the place, as if nothing had happened.

How to turn compiz on?

Comment: Have you tried adding `compiz` to your login items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to turn compiz on, run in a terminal:

```
compiz --replace
```

After that, if you wish to change the application switcher animations, perform a search of "application" under System/Preferences/CompizConfig Settings Manager and you will have the options to do what you wish.

You may also be interested into the "Scale" function, which is activated by enabling the "scale" check box in the menu and fully configurable. When enabled, press Super + W, it shows all windows from the current workspace.

Comment: I also find binding the "scale" plugin to a screen corner of great usage. This way to show all windows you need just a single fluent mouse move, then you visually select needed window and click to switch to it.